# Check if valid Xbox Live username?

Tags: api, xbox

What's the best way to check if a string is a valid Xbox Live username? I believe there is an API in relation to this, but I'm not sure which API approach is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this API](https://xboxapi.com/) is the best to use for checking if the Gamertag is valid or not.

Here is a valid Gamertag: https://xboxapi.com/profile/VNM+Jar that returns `"Success":true`

Here is an invalid Gamertag: https://xboxapi.com/profile/196jjdfd74nu9za that returns `"Success":false`

You could then do anything you wish with these values...